# Pandas group by custom frequency and get groups of indexes

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, time-series

I have a pandas timeseries `auctions` like this:

```py
problemStart                
2018-12-19 13:00:00        1
2018-12-19 14:00:00        0
2018-12-19 15:00:00        0
2018-12-19 16:00:00        0
2018-12-19 17:00:00        0
...                      ...
2021-10-29 12:00:00        0
2021-10-29 13:00:00        0
2021-10-29 14:00:00        0
2021-10-29 15:00:00        0
2021-10-29 16:00:00        1

[25084 rows x 1 columns]
```

Grouping by year gives the expected output, which is a dictionary, with first the group key, then a list of all the indices of the dataframe that are in the group.

```py
auctions.groupby(auctions.index.year).groups
```

```py
{2018: [2018-12-19 13:00:00, 2018-12-19 14:00:00, 2018-12-19 15:00:00, 2018-12-19 16:00:00, 2018-12-19 17:00:00, 2018-12-19 18:00:00, 2018-12-19 19:00:00, 2018-12-19 20:00:00, 2018-12-19 21:00:00, 2018-12-19 22:00:00, 2018-12-19 23:00:00, 2018-12-20 00:00:00, 2018-12-20 01:00:00, 2018-12-20 02:00:00, 2018-12-20 03:00:00, 2018-12-20 04:00:00, 2018-12-20 05:00:00, 2018-12-20 06:00:00, 2018-12-20 07:00:00, 2018-12-20 08:00:00, 2018-12-20 09:00:00, 2018-12-20 10:00:00, 2018-12-20 11:00:00, 2018-12-20 12:00:00, 2018-12-20 13:00:00, 2018-12-20 14:00:00, 2018-12-20 15:00:00, 2018-12-20 16:00:00, 2018-12-20 17:00:00, 2018-12-20 18:00:00, 2018-12-20 19:00:00, 2018-12-20 20:00:00, 2018-12-20 21:00:00, 2018-12-20 22:00:00, 2018-12-20 23:00:00, 2018-12-21 00:00:00, 2018-12-21 01:00:00, 2018-12-21 02:00:00, 2018-12-21 03:00:00, 2018-12-21 04:00:00, 2018-12-21 05:00:00, 2018-12-21 06:00:00, 2018-12-21 07:00:00, 2018-12-21 08:00:00, 2018-12-21 09:00:00, 2018-12-21 10:00:00, 2018-12-21 11:00:00, 2018-12-21 12:00:00, 2018-12-21 13:00:00, 2018-12-21 14:00:00, 2018-12-21 15:00:00, 2018-12-21 16:00:00, 2018-12-21 17:00:00, 2018-12-21 18:00:00, 2018-12-21 19:00:00, 2018-12-21 20:00:00, 2018-12-21 21:00:00, 2018-12-21 22:00:00, 2018-12-21 23:00:00, 2018-12-22 00:00:00, 2018-12-22 01:00:00, 2018-12-22 02:00:00, 2018-12-22 03:00:00, ...
```

However I dont understand the output I get when I do the same thing with `pd.Grouper`:

```py
auctions.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="Y")).groups
```

```py
{Timestamp('2018-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 299,
 Timestamp('2019-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 9059,
 Timestamp('2020-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 17843,
 Timestamp('2021-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 25084}
```

What are the dictionary items here? what is 299?

What I want to do is group by half year intervals, which I need the `pd.Grouper` for, but I dont understand the output it produces, and would like it to produce the same output as simply grouping by `index.year`.

---

here is the `auctions file`:
https://gist.github.com/charelF/96b5e6fb765be28377794ed27fd20ad6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a better way than `groups` to get the indices, namely `indices`:

```py
auctions.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='Y', key="problemStart")).indices
```

To get it exactly how I want:

```py
{k:auctions.index[v] for k,v in auctions.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='Y')).indices.items()}
```

returns

```py
{Timestamp('2018-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): DatetimeIndex(['2018-12-19 13:00:00', '2018-12-19 14:00:00', '2018-12-19 15:00:00', '2018-12-19 16:00:00', '2018-12-19 17:00:00', '2018-12-19 18:00:00', ...
```

since that is pretty similar to the desired:

```py
{2018: [2018-12-19 13:00:00, 2018-12-19 14:00:00, 2018-12-19 15:00:00, 2018-12-19 16:00:00, 2018-12-19 17:00:00, 2018-12-19 18:00:00, 2018-12-19 19:00:00, 2018-12-19 20:00:00, 2018-12-19 21:00:00, 2018-12-19 22:00:00, 2018-12-19 23:00:00, 2018-12-20 00:00:00, 2018-12-20 01:00:00, 2018-12-20 02:00:00, 2018-12-20 03:00:00, 2018-12-20 04:00:00, 2018-12-20 05:00:00, 2018-12-20 06:00:00, 2018-12-20 07:00:00, 2018-12-20 08:00:00, 2018-12-20 09:00:00, 2018-12-20 10:00:00, 2018-12-20 11:00:00, 2018-12-20 12:00:00, 2018-12-20 13:00:00, 2018-12-20 14:00:00, 2018-12-20 15:00:00, 2018-12-20 16:00:00, 2018-12-20 17:00:00, 2018-12-20 18:00:00, 2018-12-20 19:00:00, 2018-12-20 20:00:00, 2018-12-20 21:00:00, 2018-12-20 22:00:00, 2018-12-20 23:00:00, 2018-12-21 00:00:00, 2018-12-21 01:00:00, 2018-12-21 02:00:00, 2018-12-21 03:00:00, 2018-12-21 04:00:00, 2018-12-21 05:00:00, 2018-12-21 06:00:00, 2018-12-21 07:00:00, 2018-12-21 08:00:00, 2018-12-21 09:00:00, 2018-12-21 10:00:00, 2018-12-21 11:00:00, 2018-12-21 12:00:00, 2018-12-21 13:00:00, 2018-12-21 14:00:00, 2018-12-21 15:00:00, 2018-12-21 16:00:00, 2018-12-21 17:00:00, 2018-12-21 18:00:00, 2018-12-21 19:00:00, 2018-12-21 20:00:00, 2018-12-21 21:00:00, 2018-12-21 22:00:00, 2018-12-21 23:00:00, 2018-12-22 00:00:00, 2018-12-22 01:00:00, 2018-12-22 02:00:00, 2018-12-22 03:00:00, ...
```